# Google Dependency failed to resolve in Android studio Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I wanted to integrate Google Login in my application. So I added Google Auth dependency to it. After adding the dependency, It was not resolving. So I updated all my google dependencies as below:

[image]

Also, Have a look at my build gradle on app level and Min, target and compile SDK version with build tools version as below:

[image]

[image]

After adding all the above settings, I clean and rebuild the project and Synced the gradle. After the gradle synced properly, It gave me below errors:

[image]

Now, I am scratching my head for the last few hours that from where 17.3.4 dependency is coming for all the other google dependencies which I haven't added with that version.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: All dependency version should be same.
Try with same version dependency.

Comment: Tried that too. Same error with different dependency version. I tried it with 16.0.0. But still got the same errors with different version higher than it.